# Giving input to background processes

Tags: permissions, process, git

Is there any way to give input to background processes or which run as daemon processes?

I was coding some Puppet configuration files and I had to push them to some remote machine. For that purpose I used git.

So I created a bare repository on that remote machine and used a git hook which would update the file after each push. So to update in `/etc/puppet` of the server machine I need to authenticate as root of that machine... But git essentially does this transfer through SSH (in the background ).

I tried to use `/bin/expect` to provide username and password for root of the remote machine but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding exactly what you're doing or what you're not managing to do. Could you give an example/commands you're running maybe so we get a more concrete idea of the task at hand?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4869937/309483

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't exactly answer the question you asked, you presented us with an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

The answer to your real problem is to **set up SSH keys**.

- On the client side run `ssh-keygen` as the user who will be performing the operation.
- Copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.
- Make sure `~/.ssh/` is mode 0700 on the server.

You will no longer need to enter a password to connect.